# Testing my app on different devices

Tags: android, android-studio

I have developed an Android app and it's ready for launching , now i wanted to test it on different possible devices ,but unfortunately i can't afford all the devices physically and I can't download emulators for all the Android devices , is there any way to test my app in different Android devices and see how they work on that device's

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: you should be able to emulate a fair amount of screen size's / android versions from android studio?

Comment: Yes , but i wanted to see the working of the app, not a screenshot like picture.

Comment: Maybe you have friends with different devices?  send them the apk file per email and turn them into Guinea Pigs

Comment: @Barns maybe this can work ,but not an efficient way ,anyway thanks for the suggestion . (Guinea pigs - lol )

Comment: The emulator allows the app to 'work' though, like there isnt much difference between the emulator and the real device other than hardware specifications/limitations

Comment: I realize it is not the optimal solution. But, it has been my experience that emulators are not a good indication of how the app actually behaves on a real device. In any case, having friends test your app is always a good idea--if for no other reason as to hear their praise about how good it is (or not!). But, seriously, I have gotten some really good feed back about the UI, UX and wishes for additional functions from friends. Good luck with the app!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com), it is very light and clean, better than AVD (Android Virtual Device)

Comment: Good to know!  Book Marked that website. Thanks Abner!

Comment: I think this may work , I'll try that @abner , thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

it's the android studio should be able to test almost every screen size you can also try testing on android emulators like bluestacks and others they'll help

Comment: I assume you meant :: BlueStacks

Comment: yes that's what i meant i should edit it i think thank you also try the droid4x it's helpful too